# How to test if a function in props has been called from my computed property using jest | vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

## Context

I wanted to test a computed property in vueJS, this computed property calls 2 functions that are declared from the props of the component and I wanted to test if the functions are called during the execution of the computed property.

#### *example*:

```js
/* code */

props:{
  myFunction:{
    type: Function,
    default: () => null
  },
  data: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
},
computed:{
  myComputed(){
     this.data ? myFunction(this.data) : null
  }
}

/* code */
```

The code above is a dummy code and his only purpose is to serve as an example to explain my problem, how can test if myFunction() has been called with jest?

I've already tried to use this jest expect method but it always returns whether 'Mycomponent.props().myFunction is not a function' or 'expect(...).hasBeenCalled is not a function'
I know I'm doing this wrong but I don't understand how to use it in this case even after reading the doc.
For now I have something like:

```js
    expect(component.props().myFunction()).toHaveBeenCalled() //does not work
/* and I tried something like that : */
     expect(component.computed.myComputed.call({myFunction : () => 0}))
     .expect(component.props().myFunction()).toHaveBeenCalled() // does not work
```

Can someone give me a little push ?

Comment: when you create the component wrapper for tests you should be able to specify the propsData, pass in jest.fn

Comment: Yes I usually declare the props in local object to easily modify the value of the props between tests and I pass this object in the call methods, this way I don't need to mount the component to just test a bit of calculus since this computed does not affect rendering directly

Comment: oh wait do you call myFunction? `expect(component.props().myFunction())` this is void isnt it? shouldnt it be `expect(component.props().myFunction)`

Comment: Well that's the question, I'm pretty new to jest in vueJS so I tried something to test if myFunction has been called by myComputed, since myFunction came from the props I don't know how to get this information, maybe the question wasn't clear

Comment: yeah sometimes one has to make assumptions, in this case i thought you checked with jest docs ;) https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalled , and you are asking about the pattern

Comment: I read the doc and some article from [here](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/), and I have to admit I saw what you just sent here but I think I don't understand how to use it in this case, since I need to call myComputed in order to test if myFunction has been called I'm a bit lost I guess

Comment: i think its best when you just start here https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/ as this can actually unit test components - also considering lifecycle